# UIButton condition works in single index path row

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I am creating a foot ball match app, I am having two buttons in UITableviewcell, I am checking the conditions for that, my conditions are working on the whole table view. My problem is: my conditions should works every single row of the table.see my image in that L button select means V button should not change its working in 0th index path,but next index path when i select V button is not changing, **my conditions should works every singe index path row**.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"HistoryCell";
CustomizedCellView *cell = (CustomizedCellView *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CustomizedCellView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
} 
button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button1.frame = CGRectMake(80, 27, 36, 36);
[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"l"ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(radiobtn2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  button1.tag = 56;
[cell.contentView addSubview:button1];

button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button3.frame = CGRectMake(240, 27, 36, 36);
[button3 setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"v"ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button3.tag = 57;
[button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(radiobtn2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [cell.contentView addSubview:button3];
}
- (void)radiobtn2:(UIButton *)button
{


if (button.tag == 56)
        {

            if ([button isSelected]) {
                [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"l.png"]
                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
               NSLog(@" select");
                [button setSelected:NO];
            } else {
                [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lblue.png"]
             forState:UIControlStateSelected];
               NSLog(@"not select");
             [button setSelected:YES];
            }
           }else
        {
        }


 if (button.tag == 57)
                {
                    if ([button isSelected]) {
                        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"v.png"]
                                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                  NSLog(@"select");
                    [button setSelected:NO];
                } else {
                    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vblue.png"]
                            forState:UIControlStateSelected];
                    NSLog(@"not select");
                    [button setSelected:YES];
                }
            } else
            {
                NSLog(@"button3 == 1");
            }
```

[image]. please help me, what should i do hear, i am struggling lot please any one help me in coding. **i need my condition this like** [image]

Comment: please clarify your requirement

Comment: This is not a accurate way to add a selector for a UIButton. If you can write radiobtn2 method login inside your CustomizedCellView Cell, that will do your work.

Comment: my requirement is like 2nd image. i want to check the conditions for each row. when i select L button v button should not change, when i select V button L button should not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some changes added, please check

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"HistoryCell";
   CustomizedCellView *cell = (CustomizedCellView *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[CustomizedCellView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
      UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
      button1.frame = CGRectMake(80, 27, 36, 36);
      [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"l"ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lblue.png"]
             forState:UIControlStateSelected];
      [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(radiobtn2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

     button1.tag=1; 
     [cell.contentView addSubview:button1];

      UIButton *button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
      button3.frame = CGRectMake(240, 27, 36, 36);
      [button3 setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"v"ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [button3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vblue.png"]
                            forState:UIControlStateSelected];

      [button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(radiobtn2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [cell.contentView addSubview:button3];
  button3.tag=2;
} 



- (void)radiobtn2:(UIButton *)sender
{

    UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell *)sender.superview;
    sender.selected=YES;

   if(sender.tag==1){
      UIButton *otherButton=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
      otherButton.selected=NO;
   }else if(sender.tag==2){
      UIButton *otherButton=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
      otherButton.selected=NO;
   }
}
```

This should work for you. However you should use Custom Cell for designs like this, and use data to toggle state..

Cheers.

Comment: bro i want to check the conditions between two buttons.   
my requirement is like 2nd image. i want to check the conditions for each row. when i select L button v button should not change, when i select V button L button should not change.

Comment: @Raj You mean, if one selected another shouldn't, RIGHT?

Comment: my image is not changing bro

Comment: Have you applied my changes? It should work, this is correct implementation.. I have Tested.

Comment: You need to set image for selected state while you are creating the button, then only it will work.. see this [button3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vblue.png"]
                            forState:UIControlStateSelected]; See my answer properly.. And too you need to move you creation of button inside if(cell==nil) block.

Comment: but i have to ask small doubt, i want to take the value of selected button how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

You should not set the same button tags for all rows. Set the `button.tag = 1000+indexPath.row` for the one button and `2000+indexPath.row` for the V button (in order to separate them). So when the action is triggered you know which row it belongs to and only that will be set as selected.

Comment: Same answer :-) Define different button tags for each row.

Answer (score 0):

```
 I think your problem is with button tag. from your current code every 
buttons will get same tag.. 
do this
declare a variable glabally,  NSIndexPath *butIndexPath;
in cellForRow method ,after cell==nil method
put this code
butIndexPath.row=2*indexpath.row;
then use
button1.tag=butIndexPath.row;
button3.tag=butIndexPath.row.+1;


update button action method with below code

 change button.tag == 56 into  button.tag == butIndexPath.row
and  button.tag == 57 into   button.tag == butIndexPath.row+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You want one by one selected button image in table (First row "L" look selected , second row "V" look selected, third row "L", forth row "V", etc..)

And then you like to get state of particular button of particular row. Am i getting you correct ?

Comment: Check my answer above. I have posted after this still it's appear above this comment. Anyway just look for that. Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

       static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"HistoryCell";
       CustomizedCellView *cell = (CustomizedCellView *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
       if (cell == nil) {
          cell = [[CustomizedCellView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
          UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
          button1.frame = CGRectMake(80, 27, 36, 36);
          [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"l"ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
          [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lblue.png"]
                 forState:UIControlStateSelected];
          [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(radiobtn2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

         button1.tag=1; 
         [cell.contentView addSubview:button1];

          UIButton *button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
          button3.frame = CGRectMake(240, 27, 36, 36);
          [button3 setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"v"ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
          [button3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vblue.png"]
                                forState:UIControlStateSelected];

          [button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(radiobtn2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:button3];
      button3.tag=2;
    } 

    if ((indexPath.row % 2) == 0) {
        // Make left button selected by default by using setSelected property
    }
    else
    {
        // Make right button selected by default by using setSelected property
    }

}
    So now when ever you do any action you will get appropriated state
```